# How to add data points in ggplot curve?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a curve using ggplot. I have the data which I calculated mean and se and stored in data. Then I used ggplot to plot the curve. So far everything looks good. But, I would like to scatter all three replicate data points for each time point and dose over their respective mean error bar. Can anyone help with my query. Here is my code:

```
structure(list(values = c(5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
25L, 15L, 10L, 30L, 17L, 9L, 27L, 14L, 8L, 75L, 45L, 20L, 80L, 
50L, 25L, 90L, 50L, 30L, 150L, 100L, 50L, 160L, 110L, 60L, 170L, 
120L, 70L), dose = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2.5", 
"5", "10"), class = "factor"), time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 30L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")


my_data$dose <- as.factor(my_data$dose)
head(my_data)

library(dplyr)
data <- group_by(my_data, dose, time) %>%
 summarise(
  count = n(),
  mean = mean(values, na.rm = TRUE),
  sd = sd(values, na.rm = TRUE),
  se   = sd / sqrt(n())
  )

data

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=mean, group=dose)) +
 geom_point(size = 1)+
 geom_smooth(aes(linetype=dose), color = "black", se = F, size = 0.5)+
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean - se, ymax=mean + se), width=1.8) + 
 labs(x ="sec", y = "Units") +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 35, 5), limits = c(-1, 35), expand = c(0, 0))+
 scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 200, 20), limits = c(-10, 200), expand = c(0, 0))+
 scale_linetype_manual(values=c( "dashed",  "dotted", "solid"),
                        labels = c("2.5", "5", "10"))
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points to be plotted are present in the original data set `my_data` but not in the aggregated data. In the latter only the mean values are present. So argument `data = my_data` must be passed to `geom_point`.

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = mean, group = dose)) +
  geom_point(data = my_data, 
             mapping = aes(x = time, y = values), 
             size = 1) +
  geom_smooth(data = data, 
              mapping = aes(linetype = dose), 
              color = "black", 
              se = FALSE, size = 0.5)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width=1.8) + 
  labs(x ="sec", y = "Units") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 35, 5), 
                     limits = c(-1, 35), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 200, 20), 
                     limits = c(-10, 200), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c( "dashed",  "dotted", "solid"),
                        labels = c("2.5", "5", "10"))

p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful. I am wondering if I can show  additionally mean_se error bar (i.e. some dot (mean) in the middle of upper and lower whiskers). Is this possible?

Comment: @user12582271 Yes, it is possible. Use the same trick, in `geom_point` pass the appropriate data set to argument `data` and set the `aes` to the values you want to plot.